# make a playlist of youtube videos in video-js

Tags: javascript, youtube, video.js, playlist, video-player

Is it possible to make a playlist of youtube videos in video-js?
i'm using [video-js-youtube](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) for supporting youtube videos and [video-js-playlist](https://github.com/tim-peterson/videojs-playlist) to make a playlist of videos (which are on my server)

however i wish to make a playlist of a set of youtube videos, is it possible?